# Processing json object through javascript with react

Tags: javascript, java, html, json, reactjs

So I'm trying to build an application. Where I have a Java API that provides the data from the database as a json object. This I want to pass through an html website using javascript and react to visualize. I got this piece of code to start with as my javascript code

```
const url = 'localhost:8080/getcomments?testcaseid=1';
fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      var rootElement =
        React.createElement('div', {},
          React.createElement('h1', {}, "test"),
          React.createElement('ul', {},
            React.createElement('li', {},
              React.createElement('h2', {}, data.comment)
            )
          )
        )
     ReactDOM.render(rootElement, document.getElementById('react-app'))
    });
```

The url returns when run in a browser

```
[{"id":50,"testcaseId":1,"userId":1,"comment":"dit is voor de eerste testcase"}]
```

But when I run this with the html page I just get a blank page. Then I thought it was maybe the react code and change the data.comment intoo "hello", but also got no return. When I copied the react piece outside the fetch I get some return. Also when I run the html page I don't get any response on my Java API. but when I run the url I get a lot of response.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: make rootElement global? its inside of an anonymous function... Add *var rootElement;* into the first line remove the other var...

Comment: I tried this but I don't get any reaction on my API?

Comment: It seems that It never goes into the function itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to debug the response first.

try

```
.then((response) => {
   var parseResult = response.json();
   console.log(parseResult);
   return parseResult;
 })
```

make sure the json data is correct first, then you can debug the react code.

Comment: I did this and in the console I got the next error into the console "index.html:1 Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:8080/getcomments?testcaseid=1. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

Comment: Got this going with an addon in Chrome. And I see my object but how do I get that same object?

Comment: CORS issue. are you requesting from other domain?
try add the header on the request to allow cross-origin request.

Comment: I'm just working localhost. And how can I add the header?

Comment: here, try this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch